# No battery status icon

Tags: indicator

I recently upgraded to 11.10 from 11.04, everything went fine, still hate unity and all that.  But my battery status is not showing up at all, even on my laptop.  There isn't even any spaces for it, there is only the Mail Icon, Wirelesss Icon, Sound, Time, [username] and Power.  I have tried several different things to get it, but I am at a loss.  Please help

- I've already tried to install `indicator-power` and it is installed.

Comment: this might sound stupid, but does ubuntu come in different versions, such as one for Desktops and one for Laptops?

Comment: I think the battery icon won't be visible in the panel if it is fully charged. Check back later when the battery is not full.

Comment: i used it today, after a full night of charging.  It gave me about 4 hours of use and then all of a sudden shut down, probably due to the lack of battery.  I did not see the battery indicator at any point the whole day.

Comment: I am going to try to reinstall.

Comment: What workaround / fixes did you end up trying?  Did anything so any promise / partial improvement?

Answer (score 19):

I found that my power indicator had simply crashed. Executing the following in a terminal restarted it in no time:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service &disown
```

Answer (score 15):

the indicator is:

```
indicator-power
```

Make sure that is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

If it is installed I would try re-installing it.

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-power
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

I have not found an indicator file to edit that controls them loading or not.

Comment: when you remove indicator-power it also remove unity-control-center and many other tweaks so after you remove & install indicator-power you need to install webaccounts-extension-common and it will  install unity-control-center and all other tweaks

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem on 12.04 ... No power indicator applet (upon login -- saw one AT the login screen).

Running `gsettings list-recursively|grep settings-daemon` spat out that:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false
```

In terminal,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
```

... logged out and back in and I was good.

This was a fresh install from ISO of 12.04, so for those of you seeing *two* icons, you might want to set "....plugins.power active false" and see if one goes away.

Comment: I'm not seeing that here on two fresh installs (32- and 64-bit). The indicator not showing seems to be the consequence of the disabled power plugin in g-s-d. Are you sure you didn't disable it yourself (maybe added anything to the kernel boot line in GRUB)? Anyways, I suggest to [file a bug report](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) (I'd pick the gnome-settings-daemon package - don't worry, if that's wrong, bug control people will fix it for you).

Comment: Mine came back automatically after running the commands. No need for logging out and back in again.

Answer (score 5):

The indicator is called: `indicator-power`. You can try this 3 solutions preferably by their current order:

#### 1)

**Confirm that it is installed:**

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

**If installed**, try removing it and reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-power

sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

#### 2)

**If no avail, run the configuration utility:**

```
gnome-settings-daemon
```

#### 3)

If you got here, it's time to try an alternative monitor package:

[How to add a detailed battery indicator to Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/)

---

This solutions were found at [11.10 No battery status icon - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon)

Answer (score 2):

Use dconf-editor.  If you don't have it installed, you can do so, by just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

[image: dconf-editor window]

Comment: This worked for me after trying all the above. Thanks buddy!!

Answer (score 1):

You have just updated to **Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)** from 11.04 ..

**Note:** *I did that too, on my netbook.  I eventually gave up, and installed a new Ubuntu 11.10 instead.*

I have a battery indicator, working correctly, showing percentage, etc.

There is an outstanding (unresolved) bug for this issue in LaunchPad.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-mono/+bug/801180/comments/30

SUGGESTIONS: (in no particular order)

1. Change theme to (or away from) 'Radiance'.  Make sure this is not an icon issue.
2. Purge and re-install **indicator-power** (as suggested by **cprofitt**).
3. Remove any revenants from (older) Unity, etc.

   ```
   (get settings, for curiosity's sake)
   gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist

   (should look something like:)
   ['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'scp=-dbus-service', 'Update-notifier']

   (clear whitelist)
   gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
   ```
4. Try an alternative monitor package ..

   How to add a detailed battery indicator to Ubuntu

   http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem both with 11.10 and with 12.04, and the other answers here didn't fix it.

Running `gnome-settings-daemon` gave me a functional battery indicator again.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Right Click over the bar, so you will can configure/add/move applets. With the complete indicators miniaplication, come the battery indicator.
That work for me with ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As far as I can tell, <Alt> right click does absolutely nothing for the Unity top panel.  That was Gnome 2.x convention.

Answer (score 0):

Fighting with this issue, I have found that the proprietary driver modules for the NVIDIA graphic card, were indeed messing up with the battery icon, with the volup and voldown function, and with the shutoff button in the keyboard.

I simply deactivated these controllers and it came back to normal. Go figure. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Battery indicator should run with the Unity Panel, but sometimes is inhibited for strange reasons.

You can try to force the daemon to run, writing `gnome-settings-daemon` in the terminal.

If it works, and you see the battery indicator in the panel, you can add the command to the Startup Applications.

[How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

It work great for me, I hope it can help you!

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Comment: Ok thanks! I did this to achieve as much as posible people. I'm not encourage to mark questions as duplicate, but if you recommend it... then I will do next time. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a long time.

acer aspire 5553 on ubuntu 13.04.  I had no battery under `/proc/acpi/battery` or `/sys/class/power_supply`

Just updating the linux kernel to latest 3.11.1 solved it. Maybe this might help many.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/kernel-3-11-1-released-install-upgrade-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else try restarting the power applet with a Hang-Up signal.

```
pkill --signal HUP indicator-power && echo $?
```

A status code of *0* should be displayed.