# Battery indicator missing in gnome classic

Tags: gnome, indicator, battery

I had upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 from Ubuntu 11.10 and I am also using gnome classic. But the Battery indicator is Missing in the taskbar. So i followed the link (http://askubuntu.com/questions/78979/battery-indicator-missing) found here..

I had used the same command mentioned here. But the Battery Icon was not visible.. I am using dell laptop with intel pentium.

rgds,
Biju

Answer (score 10):

app the "indicator applet complete" by going in add panel option, via pressing windows+atl+right mouse click keys on top panel.

Comment: I think you mean "Indicator Applet Complete", and thanks! This worked for me too.

Comment: For more information see http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/indicator-applet-ported-to-gnome-3-can.html

Comment: @Amit you are awesome..

Comment: Just Alt+Right Click works too