# Battery indicator missing, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: indicator, battery

There is a closed , question at [Battery Indicator Missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78979/battery-indicator-missing).
But I have the problem and have not found any solution yet.
Also asked a question about it on Launchpad but no replies again. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/197436

I updated the kernel from 3.2 to 3.4 precise. I have ubuntu 12.04, on 64 bit machine, dell E6400.
I tried

```
chawla@chawla-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install indicator-power
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
indicator-power is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
```

but nothing works,  anyone have the idea about it?
Thanks

Comment: What you filed is not a bug but a support question.  Just an FYI.

Comment: Why did you update the kernel? Where are you installing it from? Who is maintaining that kernel with security patches and bug fixes?

Answer (score 5):

I had accidentally hit "Show Time in Menu Bar" when clicking on the battery on the menu bar in Gnome. This apparently hid the battery quite well. Here's what I needed:

Run `dconf-editor`. (Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and type in `dconf-editor`, and hit "Run".) Browse to `com > canonical > indicator > power` and check the "show-time" setting. Your battery icon should re-appear immediately. "show-time" was the one I needed to change, but note that if "icon-policy" is "never", you will need to select one of the other options for the icon to appear.

(Note: This thing is buggy as hell. There's System Settings > Power, which has "Show battery status in the menu bar", and this settings is blank for me, so you would *think* selecting "when battery is present" would correct the problem. Unfortunately, it not only does it not "Show the battery status in the menu bar when the battery is present", but it also doesn't stick: leaving the dialog and coming back returns me to a blank as my selected option.)

Answer (score 2):

## First way

Try to use this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-power && sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

and please say what you get, for me to write way 2

Comment: **(1)** If you know more than one way, please edit your answer to include the second way *even if you know the first way worked for this OP*. On Ask Ubuntu we're trying to create reusable answers that help lots of people, so even if one way helps the OP here, another answer to the same question can definitely be posted. **(2)** You don't need to remove and install a package in separate `apt-get` steps, to reinstall it. You can just use `sudo apt-get --reinstall install indicator-power`. If you want to purge global configuration files: `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install indicator-power`.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried everything on this page but didn't solve my problem of the battery indicator missing.

So I decided to restart the computer and try that, but no hope still the same, no indicator. I took the battery out of my laptop for about 5 seconds and put it in and turn my laptop on and tada! it's back on the tool bar.

Maybe that's something you'd wanna try first especially for first time Linux user so you don't have to put in code without knowing what they are before doing them. That's how I am with some terminal codes... I"m scared to put them in and its gonna mess something up even more.

If battery indicator is not showing, here's my solution:

1. Turn off comp/laptop
2. Remove battery for about 5-15 secs (just to make sure)
3. Place battery back in
4. Boot comp/laptop back on

and at very login screen you should be able to see the battery indicator without login in.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

For battery/power enter this command in terminal than logout and login back:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

[image: dconf-editor window]

Comment: Can you list the steps displayed by your graphic, not everyone has sight, so explain with words, and use graphics as backup.

Comment: Oh and don't spam answers, If you see a question that is the exact flag it as a duplicate, don't answer with the same answer. http://askubuntu.com/a/162275/47291 , http://askubuntu.com/a/165024/47291