# What is the gnome command for the battery applet?

Tags: 12.10, indicator, awesome

It used to be gnome-power-manager or something of that sort, but now I can't seem to find it. When I run gnome-session from within awesome, it loads all the applets, i.e. nm-applet and the keyboard layout switcher, yet it doesn't load the battery applet, and so I'd like to launch it with a command.

Comment: Try `gnome-settings-daemon`

Comment: @devav2 Gnome-session launches gnome-settings-daemon, so I'm already running it. It doesn't add a battery indicator to my system tray, which is why I need to find the command.

Comment: possible duplicate: check out the 2nd comment. http://askubuntu.com/questions/148971/battery-indicator-missing-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @Suhaib No, the issue is not that the battery indicator doesn't show up under certain conditions (e.g. when charging), but rather that it doesn't exist at all. This problem would be solved if I knew the command to run the applet.

Comment: My problem is that I don't want the integrated indicator since it has components I never use, but I can't find a stand-alone applet for newer Ubuntus...

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The mentioned ppa seems no longer available as of April 2014. Please check before following this solution. For more information see the comments below this answer.

---

First Install **Battery-Status** by Running following command in terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install battery-status
```

To run ‘Battery Status’ as an Indicator-applet  in Ubuntu you’ll need to run the following command in a terminal:

```
/usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator
```

To launch the indicator mode on log-in add it to your ‘Start-up applications’ in `System > Preferences > Startup Applications`, entering the command above in the command field.

Comment: The PPA maintainer hasn't built battery-status for 12.10, so I get `E: Unable to locate package battery-status`. Isn't there a default battery indicator command that doesn't require adding a PPA?

Comment: Yes, You are right, I checked out. You have to wait for that.

Comment: If by accident you followed these instruction and find the ppa repository is no longer there, here is how to fix your apt sources: http://askubuntu.com/a/609048/1467

Comment: @mit, you are right, it is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to restore the menu-bar icon by using the Dconf editor. This is probably already installed, but if not, it's in the Sofware Center as Dconf Editor. Note that's a title not the package name. In Synaptic it's dconf-tools. The command line is sudo apt-get install dconf-tools.

This is a low-level editor for system settings, so be careful.

To get to the power icon setting:

com --> canonical --> indicator --> power. After clicking power, look for "icon-policy" in the right pane. Presumably it will say "never." Change it to "present"

Comment: "icon-policy" already says "present."

Answer (score 1):

the default battery indicator in ubuntu is part of the 'unity-panel-service' it's called 'indicator-power' and can't – as far as I know – be called on its own.

However you can try to install 'indicator-applet' and then 'indicator-power' if it's not already installed.
And then try launching 'indicator-applet' and see what you end up with.

**Sorry for bad formatting my cell phone somehow doens't get the spacing for the code right**

Comment: I suggest you *fix* the formatting instead of putting a bold-font banner at the bottom of the post.