# Unable to update battery-status ppa

Tags: apt, update-manager, ppa

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm getting this error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

when I try this

```
sudo apt-get update
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That PPA is no longer available. You should consider using another PPA to provide whatever app you want to install.

To remove this PPA, run the following two commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/iaz-battery-status*
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem!! I'm new to Ubuntu so I don't really know what it does...!! Should I install any alternatives to battery-status??

Comment: If you don't know what it is, it most likely doesn't matter. It's not an official Ubuntu repo.

Comment: @SY13 I don't think so, you should have battery status on the dash anyhow.