# Battery Monitor Not Showing on boot up of Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity, battery, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No battery status icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon)

When I boot up Ubuntu 11.10, my battery monitor does not show up, it only does when the battery is low, or I plug in my power cord. I want it to come up even if I am on battery on start up. When the battery monitor is on, putting in watch -n 1 acpi -b in Terminal works like a charm. I installed Jupiter to help with power retaining, but I would love some help on getting my battery monitor up. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity.

Is there a solution to make my battery monitor start on boot up?