# Unable to locate package battery-status

Tags: 11.10, indicator

Since upgrading to 11.10. my battery status icon is missing. I've tried the solutions suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon), with no luck. In particular, trying to add the alternative package described [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/), I get the error message `Unable to locate package battery-status`.

Anyone know how to locate this package (or indeed how else to get the default battery status icon working)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by a comment, there's no package for 11.10 yet. However, there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/battery-status/+bug/896731) opened in launchpad regarding this; so, if you're not in a hurry, I suggest to subscribe to the bug to get the updates when the status of the same changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Battery Status PPA to the package manager.

To do so, close Synaptic and open a Terminal.

Enter this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status
```

And type your password, when prompted.

When that's done, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, open up Synaptic and search for battery-status and you should find it.

The instructions were taken from [here](https://launchpad.net/~iaz/+archive/battery-status), after a Google search...
Hope it works for you!

Comment: There is no 11.10 package for that PPA. The answer to this question is "there isn't a package for `battery-status`"

Comment: @jrg Thanks, that would explain it. I take it that means I need to find a different battery indicator?