# Battery-indicator does not work on 12.04

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No battery status icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon)

The battery-indicator only appears in the login screen. Using 12.04 Ubuntu 64 bit. It has always happened since I installed from a fresh install of 12.04.