# Display dims when not in use and it turns off when not in use or while watching movies

Tags: 11.10, display, power-management, screensaver

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and am using it on dell xps laptop now my problem is that Ubuntu does not provide power utility form where I can manage brightness of my screen, when to turn it off, after how much time it should dim...etc etc. Please provide me with some advance power utility where I can manage it all.

thanks in advance

Comment: Is your PC not being recognized as a laptop?

Comment: Do you have a battery indicator icon (top right of screen)?  See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon

Comment: I would suggest an upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Dash Home button and type `screen`. and click on the Screen Control Panel that comes up. There you can tell Ubuntu not to dim and and then turn off the monitor (but not brightness, you may be able to do that by pressing marked keys on your laptop). I'm not aware of software to do that on 11.10.

If you take Ross Fleming's advice and update to 12.04 you can use the *Brightness and Lock* control panel to control screen brightness and when the monitor is turned off.