# Missing battery/power indiciator

Tags: laptop, indicator, 15.04, battery

I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04, and the battery indicator seems to not be present. It doesn't appear on the login/lock screen either.

[I found this answer from back in 2011](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon), however none of the answers/workarounds seem to work.

- I've tried reinstalling indicator-power
- Used gsettings to try to set the suggested setting, no luck.
- Starting gnome-settings-daemon manually had no effect.
- I don't have the Nvidia proprietary drivers enabled (Though I plan to activate them sooner or later)

Comment: Okay, this is *really* weird. When I boot up my laptop (MacBook Pro, Mid 2012) by holding Alt, then choosing EFI Boot -> Which loads rEFInd -> Ubuntu, I get the battery icon... So I wonder if there's some kind of bootloader/driver not being loaded when the computer just auto starts into Ubuntu.

Comment: ... Just restarted my laptop again, annnnd it's gone once more (went through rEFInd again). I honestly have no clue what's going on here. It's not just the applet though, the system isn't detecting the battery at all (installed acpi, ran it, and no battery is outputted).