# no battery indicator (bug?)

Tags: 14.04, indicator, battery

I know there are similar posts (I even post this question two months ago with no replies) but I could not figure out a solution. Also, searching in Internet did not give anything useful.

I am not able to see the battery indicator on the panel in my Ubuntu 14.04 installation. I changed the power setting to 'When battery is present', used dconf-editor to check if the power-daemon was active, also purged and installed 'indicator-power' to no effect. I spent a lot of time reading various relevant threads in Internet but still no result. Anything else that I can try to get it back?
Is this a bug?

I even followed the instructions: [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-check-the-battery-status-via-command-line-interface/) .
I can check e.g. the temprature by

```
$ acpi -t
```

but

```
$ acpi
```

does not produce a result.

(AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 )

PS.

A  colleague of mine recently purchased a Dell laptop with the same version of Ubuntu preinstalled. In his laptop there is battery indication!

Comment: Is your laptop the same model as your colleague's?

Comment: No. Mine one is a Toshiba Satelite originally coming with Windows 7 and installing Ubuntu as dualbooting (sorry for possibe improper use of terms).

Comment: It kind of made it seem like you had a Dell as well. A different model could make a difference, but a completely different brand shouldn't be compared. Now, you can try this, but since it's for 11.04, there's no guarantee it'll work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have already tried it; no results! Do you think it is really a bug or it has to do with my pc or even with the pc's battery? Showing the related posts I am very puzzled!

Comment: I'm not sure. You could try going to 15.04

Comment: I tried 15.04,  following  http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/ . No workaround. It may  be a problem of my hardware but there are 9 similar posts  in the forum. Quite strange...

Comment: So many similar posts actually points to it being a hardware issue. Ubuntu probably doesn't work with your battery controller.

Comment: Is there workaround for it? (except for getting rid of my laptop:-)!)

Comment: You might be able to get some sort of third party hardware/battery monitoring app.

Comment: Ok, this has become like chat...but do you have sth to propose?

Comment: Just search `battery monitor` or `hardware monitor ` in the software center