# Reverting sudo apt-get purge indicator-power

Tags: apt, indicator, battery

I ran the command  `sudo apt-get purge indicator-power` because my battery icon is not displaying. After running this command I ran  `sudo apt-get install indicator-power` but the purge command appeared to have removed some other tweaks.

What are the other commands I need to run to revert this?

Also, this fix unfortunately did not fix the battery display problem so there is still that issue to address.

I have tried all solutions outlined in this post:
[No battery status icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon)

Unfortunately, none of them seem to fix the indicator.

I am new to Ubuntu so thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: I highly recommend recovery via the backup you made to cover yourself prior to purging and starting over with the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to `indicator-power` but I can answer the main part of the question:

`apt purge` deletes all the configuration files shipped with a package. If you make alterations and then `purge`, your changes are lost. You could attempt data recovery techniques but something like that is a needle in a haystack.