# How do I get the battery status on the status bar?

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a new custom PC (Proteus series from PC Specialist). These computers are not tested on Linux, so I'm not expecting any support from them. Maybe you can help?

I have tried everything from this page: [No battery status icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon)

I ran `gsettings list-recursively|grep settings-daemon` and got:
`org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true`

After trying to check battery status from command line, as in here: [How to check battery status using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal) , I got:

```
username@boxname:~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
native-path:          ACAD
power supply:         yes
updated:              Tue 25 Jul 2017 01:21:11 BST (74344 seconds ago)
has history:          no
has statistics:       no
line-power
warning-level:       none
online:              no
icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'
```

I thought maybe there are special drivers for batteries which Ubuntu needs to install, but it turns out I was wrong about that.

I'm at my wit's end. Don't really know what's wrong, or what to do. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939764/how-do-i-sanity-check-my-acpi-tables) may help you determine what is wrong.

Comment: From memory... *(I just switched from Unity to GNOME)*... there's a setting in System Settings that sounds like "show battery icon always, show battery icon only when charging, never show battery indicator"... probably in the Power settings panel. Did you check its setting? Otherwise you've got a firmware/BIOS problem. Check for an updated BIOS.